# Java: Only check hashCode in equals() of immutable object

Tags: java, equals, immutability, guava, hashcode

I have an immutable object, for example a node in the Cartesian space. The class is immutable, so I cache the `hashCode` for very fast hashing.

```
private final int hashCode;

private final double x, y, z;

public Node(final double x, final double y, final double z)
{
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.z = z;
    this.hashCode = Objects.hashCode(this.x, this.y, this.z);
}

@Override
public boolean equals(final Object obj)
{
    if (this == obj) { return true; }
    if (obj == null) { return false; }
    if (!(obj instanceof Node)) { return false; }
    final Node other = (Node) obj;
    return Objects.equal(this.x, other.x) && Objects.equal(this.y, other.y) && Objects.equal(this.z, other.z);
}

@Override
public int hashCode()
{
    return this.hashCode;
}
```

Since the `hashCode` is unique and dependent on all fields of the class AND the class is Immutable, would it be correct to only check `Node` equality based on the `hashCode`?

```
@Override
public boolean equals(final Object obj)
{
    if (this == obj) { return true; }
    if (obj == null) { return false; }
    if (!(obj instanceof Node)) { return false; }
    final Node other = (Node) obj;
    return this.hashCode == other.hashCode;
}
```

This passes all Unit Tests I have written about the properties of `equals()` and `hashCode()` and their interaction, but perhaps there is something I am missing?

Note: `Objects.hashCode()` and `Objects.equal()` are Guava classes helpful for the respective methods.

Comment: Repeat after me: **Hashcodes are not unique**.

Comment: BTW, your second `if` is a subset of the third.

Comment: @SLaks You're right, thanks. **Hashcodes are not unique**. Also thanks for the tip about the redundant null check :).

Comment: For reference, as also mentioned here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7417858/713659 , you can check for hashCode first before going into more expensive equality checks, but you cannot skip other checks.

Comment: FYI, there's no need to use `Objects.equal` in the `equals` implementation, since you're comparing primitives.  `==` will be faster and simpler.

Comment: @LouisWasserman I used it to compare the hashCode which is an int, but won't it be a problem when comparing doubles?

Comment: In this case, it's basically equivalent to `Objects.equal`.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Nope; that won't work.

You have 2<sup>32</sup> possible hashcodes and 2<sup>192</sup> possible values.

Answer (score 2):

No, but..

I guess you could check the hashcode to see whether objects **are not equal** and gain some performance there:

```
public boolean equals(final Object obj) {
   if (this == obj) { return true; }
   if (!(obj instanceof Node)) { return false; }
   final Node other = (Node) obj;

   if (this.hashCode != other.hashCode) {
      return false; // If hashcodes differ, we're sure the objects are not equal
   }
   // remainder of the actual equals implementation
}
```

Of course this will only improve performance in case most of your comparisons yield false. In case of equal objects, this will bring a performance penalty. In your example (comparing just three values), I wouldn't recommend this.