# Should I override equals() with calls to hashCode()?

Tags: java, android, hash, equals, sugarorm

I am writing an app that has an "Achievements" system, similar to Stack Overflow's badges. I am also using SugarORM to store the progress of the achievements. This is the `Achievement` class:

```
public class Achievement extends SugarRecord<Achievement>{
    @StringRes
    public int shortNameId;
    @StringRes
    public int descriptionId;
    public int progressNow;
    public int fullProgress; 
    //I am afraid that Sugar ORM will ignore private fields 
    //so I made them public. Please tell me if Sugar ORM does
    //not ignore those.
}
```

Now I want to override `equals`. And that is easy enough.

```
@Override
public boolean equals (Object other) {
    if (other == null) return false;
    if (!(other instanceof Achievement)) return false;
    Achievement a = (Achievement)other;
    return a.shortNameId == shortNameId &&
            a.descriptionId == descriptionId &&
            a.fullProgress == fullProgress;
}
```

Then I remembered that I should always override `hashCode` if I override `equals`. According to *Effective Java* by Joshua Bloch, I wrote the `hashCode` method like this:

```
@Override
public int hashCode () {
    int result = 17;
    result = result * 31 + shortNameId;
    result = result * 31 + descriptionId;
    result = result * 31 + fullProgress;
    return result;
}
```

Then I though that I should change the implementation of `equals` to

```
@Override
public boolean equals (Object other) {
    if (other == null) return false;
    if (!(other instanceof Achievement)) return false;
    Achievement a = (Achievement)other;
    return a.hashCode() == hashCode ();
}
```

After that, I thought that if I overrode `hashCode` wrongly, `equals` would not work either. However, The above implementation seems "right" to me, because I think hash codes are what makes objects equal.

P.S. Don't tell me it's personal preference. I think there must be a standard for this, right? And also I am very willing to follow standards.

Comment: Check this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7417668/java-use-hashcode-inside-of-equals-for-convenience

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general `a.hashCode()==b.hashCode()` doesn't mean that `a.equals(b)` must be true. Therefore you shouldn't rely on `hashCode` to determine equality.

The other direction, however, is true. If `a.equals(b)` then `a.hashCode()` must be equal to `b.hashCode()`.

Comment: So... my first implementation is fine?

Comment: Ok Thanks for your answer! I will accept it in 8 minutes! :)

Comment: I was happy to give the last undel vote to this pretty good question. If you still have high quality undeletion candidates (hint: "is:a deleted:1"), put them into your profil, as usual.

Comment: I disagree the answer in general. The essence of the hash codes are that no practical way should exist to find multiple objects with the same hash. If there is, then it is a serious sec hole (or bug). However, in this specific question, the hash function is very simple and even a random, unintentional collision is quite possible, saving this answer.